# could not resolve plugin artifact 'org.springframework.boot:org.springframework.boot.gradle.plugin:2.1.6.RELEASE'

Tags: spring-boot, gradle

Gradle command throwing below Exception:

FAILURE: Build failed with an exception.

- Where:
  Build file '/Users/abel/Desktop/work/gundam/build.gradle' line: 2
- What went wrong:
  Plugin [id: 'org.springframework.boot', version: '2.1.6.RELEASE'] was not found in any of the following sources:
- Gradle Core Plugins (plugin is not in 'org.gradle' namespace)
- Plugin Repositories (could not resolve plugin artifact 'org.springframework.boot:org.springframework.boot.gradle.plugin:2.1.6.RELEASE')
  Searched in the following repositories:
  Gradle Central Plugin Repository
- Try:
  Run with --stacktrace option to get the stack trace. Run with --info or --debug option to get more log output. Run with --scan to get full insights.
- Get more help at https://help.gradle.org

BUILD FAILED in 5s

Configuration:

```
plugins {
    id 'org.springframework.boot' version '2.1.6.RELEASE'
    id 'java'
}

apply plugin: 'io.spring.dependency-management'

group = 'com.demo'
version = '0.0.1-SNAPSHOT'
sourceCompatibility = '1.8'

configurations {
    compileOnly {
        extendsFrom annotationProcessor
    }
}

repositories {
    mavenCentral()
}

dependencies {
    implementation 'org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-web'
    compileOnly 'org.projectlombok:lombok'
    annotationProcessor 'org.projectlombok:lombok'
    testImplementation 'org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-test'
}
```

Comment: Try to add `apply plugin: "org.springframework.boot"`

Answer (score 1):

You should upgrade the gradle version and currently upgrade to Gradle 5.5.1 is ok，
and you need to set your idea to the current update gradle version

[image]
https://plugins.gradle.org/plugin/org.springframework.boot

Answer (score 1):

It is because of network problem, when I change the vpn , it started working

Comment: VPN was it for me too. Even though I was able to download the POM / JAR files from my browser while on the VPN, and even though --debug said it successfully downloaded the first POM file while on the VPN, disconnecting from the VPN still helped. I guess when I need to build a new Gradle project for the first time, I have to disconnect from the VPN and then reconnect.

Answer (score 0):

For me the JDK installed was compliled and hosted via company, hence even after following above options like disabling VPN, was not working.
Used `sdkman` to install a open source JDK version and defaulted `JAVA_HOME` to newly installed java version, it started working.
This might be an edge case but might help folks.